# MAMP directory removed when putting project into GIT

Tags: eclipse, mamp, egit

I have a php application in a MAMP directory. When I put the eclipse workspace in GIT (using EGIT) the MAMP directory was deleted. The contents were moved to a git subdirectory. How do I retrieve a working copy of my project?

I'm working on OS X 10.7.5 (cannot upgrade at this time) Git version is 2.1.2

Comment: Check for the .gitignore file in the Workspace in GIT.